# Determining (de)selected checkbox in a checkedListBox as they are selected

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I'm looking to setup a checkedListBox in C#. There will be roughly 50 names displayed in this checkedListBox. I'd like it so that when a name is either selected or deselected, then the program will be able to store it in a variable.

I already have the code so that when a button is pressed, it searches through all off the names in the checkedListBox and returns all those with the selected state:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameBox.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
          ArrayList.Add(nameBox.CheckedItems[i]);
}
```

I know that in Java I can use the e.getStateChange() to determine which item has either been selected or deselected:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
{
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
    {
              ArrayList = checkbox.getText();
        }    
}
```

Is there anything similar to this Java code that I can use in C# for the checkedListBox?

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: CheckedListBox has an ItemCheck event, which gives you access to the items index, current value and new value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the comment and the link, which has all you need in the example:

In your form add the private variable, such as a List:

```
 public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
   {
      private System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox checkedListBox1;
      private List<string> extraVariable;
```

then in your constructor or wherever you initialize the checkList, also initialize your extra variable:

```
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         extraVariable = new List<string>();
```

Then add your ItemChecked event, where you Add or Remove from your extra variable:

```
      private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
      {
         if(e.NewValue==CheckState.Unchecked)
         {
            extraVariable.Remove(e.NewValue);
         }
         else
         {
            extraVariable.Add(e.NewValue);
         }
      }
```

Comment: This is great thanks, possibly me being stupid, but unfortunately this is only assigning the value of 'checked' or 'unchecked' - how can I have it so that it assigns the value of text that is provided alongside the checkBox? ie, the name that has been selected/deselected...

Comment: Ah, for that, see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535652/11605410

Comment: Perfect - I'll give that a shot this afternoon - thanks for your help! :)